# Dropping foreign Key constraint

Tags: mysql

I am trying to drop a `FOREIGN KEY` but it is throwing an error.

```
**mysql> alter table traveltime drop foreign key travelid;

ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'travelid'; check that column/key exists
mysql>**
```

The column `travelid` is the foreign key referencing to another table. Here is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE traveltime;

```
CREATE TABLE `traveltime` (
  `timeid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `travelid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hour` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minute` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `travelid` (`travelid`),
  CONSTRAINT `traveltime_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`travelid`) REFERENCES `travel` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Is `travelid` a column or an index? Have a look at this thread to see if it solves your problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112513/error-1091-42000-cant-drop-created-date-check-that-column-key-exists.

Comment: You have to use the key Name not the column name

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE TRAVELTIME` run this qery edit your question with the result

Answer (score 1):

The column on which the `FOREIGN KEY` was defined was `travelid`, but you probably did not specify an identifier for the constraint itself when it was created, and MySQL created one on your behalf: `traveltime_ibfk_1`.. That's the identifier you need to target in your `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE traveltime DROP FOREIGN KEY traveltime_ibfk_1
```

Though it's difficult to visually parse, [MySQL's `ALTER TABLE` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) specify

```
ALTER [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
    [partition_options]

alter_specification:
    table_options
...
...
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol
```

... where `fk_symbol` is the constraint's identifier name, rather than the column on which it was defined (because it is possible to define multi-column FK's).